# Inserting instances of array into table using a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to insert rows of data in an array into a table. It's inserting this instead of the actual data:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $arraycount; $i++)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO contact_tariffs (qid, retail_name, tariff_name, tariff_net, tariff_rental, tariff_inclusive, tariff_length, tariff_data)
                Values ('$qid', '$quote->retail_name[$i]', '$quote->tariff_name[$i]', '$quote->tariff_net[$i]', '$quote->tariff_rental[$i]', '$quote->tariff_inclusive[$i]', '$quote->tariff_length[$i]', '$quote->tariff_data[$i]' )");                        
}
```

I have had similar problems when using `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` variables and the only solution I had for that was to temporarily transport the values into temp variables and use the temp variables to insert into the database.

Comment: Look into [string parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), use curly braces, or possibly, sprintf or prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables are too complex to use inside a string. PHP interprets `$quote->retail_name` as one variable and `$i` another, because it doesn't know where one variable ends and where the other starts. For example:

```
$i = 1;
$quote->retail_name[ 1 ] = 'foo';

echo "result: $quote->retail_name[$i]";  // --> result: Array[1]
// the above is the same as 
// echo $quote->retail_name; echo "["; echo $i; echo "];

echo "result: ".$quote->retail_name[$i]; // --> result: foo
// The above leaves the variable outside the string so it's parsed correctly.
// You could also use "result: {$quote->retail_name[$i]}"
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Try this instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $arraycount; $i++)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO contact_tariffs (qid, retail_name, tariff_name, tariff_net, tariff_rental, tariff_inclusive, tariff_length, tariff_data)
                Values ('$qid', '".$quote->retail_name[$i]."', '".$quote->tariff_name[$i]."', '".$quote->tariff_net[$i]."', '".$quote->tariff_rental[$i]."', '".$quote->tariff_inclusive[$i]."', '".$quote->tariff_length[$i]."', '".$quote->tariff_data[$i]."' )");                        
}
```

Although you should escape the values as well. Something like PDO would be preferable.

Comment: +1 for pointing to PDO, Or he can use syntax: `"'{$quote->retail_name[$i]}'"`

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by too complex, are you refering to the variables structure or the data inside it?

Comment: PHP doesn't realize that `$quote->whatever[$i]` should be one variable. It thinks that it's `$quote->whatever` and `$i` separately. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curly brackets, to insert array values directly into a double quoted string:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $arraycount; $i++)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO contact_tariffs (qid, retail_name, tariff_name, tariff_net, tariff_rental, tariff_inclusive, tariff_length, tariff_data)
                Values ('{$qid}', '{$quote->retail_name[$i]}', '{$quote->tariff_name[$i]}', '{$quote->tariff_net[$i]}', '{$quote->tariff_rental[$i]}', '{$quote->tariff_inclusive[$i]}', '{$quote->tariff_length[$i]}', '{$quote->tariff_data[$i]}' )");                        
}
```

...and please be aware of SQL injections.

Comment: Its on a trusted system so im not worrying about that :)

Comment: Properly escaping parameters in SQL-queries is not just to protect against malicious injections. Perfectly valid names like `"O'neill"` could also get you in trouble. So, no matter whether you trust all users (and/or even if you yourself are the only user), escape those damn things.